# Is there an equivalent way to do CString::GetBuffer in std::string?

Tags: c++, string

Many Windows API, such as GetModuleFileName, etc... write output to char* buffer.  But it is more convenient to use std::string.  Is there a way to have them write to std::string (or std::wstring)'s buffer directly?

Sorry for my poor English.  I'm not a native English speaker. -_-

Taworn T.

Comment: Note: for many reasons, you should always use the Unicode versions, such as `GetModuleFileNameW()`. As a bonus to making your code work on non native-english systems, which you should know a good deal about, it is more efficient because the Kernel uses Unicode internally; all ANSI versions, such as `GetModuleFileNameA()` perform flaky translations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using C++0x, then the following is guaranteed to work:

```
std::string s;
s.resize(max_length);
size_t actual_length = SomeApiCall(&s[0], max_length);
s.resize(actual_length);
```

Before C++0x the std::string contents is not guaranteed to be consecutive in memory, so the code is not reliable in theory; in practice it works for popular STL implementations.

Comment: c_str() may return a pointer to the data that, when modified (you'll have to const_cast it to modify), may not alter the original string, so it may fail even in C++0x. Though, again, it works for all popular STL implementations - but I would advise against it.

Comment: Thank zeuxcg.  I think I will go with your solution.  IMHO in practical, the only real-used STL implementations are one with VC, libstdc++ and STLport.

I have further questions:
- can I use s.begin() instead of &s[0]?
- should actual_length include null-terminate character?

Thank in advance :)

Comment: s.begin() is usually not a pointer (though it may sometimes be), so no. You can use &*s.begin(), it's the same thing as &s[0].

Comment: About the null character - resize() should take the length of the string without the terminating null character, because otherwise strlen(s.c_str()) and s.length() will be different, and you don't want that. max_length though should probably include space for null character, because you're not guaranteed that internal string representation is null-terminated either. So, presuming your API operates with lengths including null terminator, resize should be s.resize(actual_length - 1).

Comment: Thank you again zeuxcg.  Your answers are clear to understand. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

use `std::string::c_str()` to retrieve a `const char *` that is null terminated.
`std::string::data()` also returns a `const char *` but that may not be null terminated.

But like zeuxcg says, I dont suggest you to write directly in that buffer.